# XCOPY in a Batch Script - Avoid the File or Directory Prompt

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to copy files for backup before moving them into a directory to be picked up.  However, this is failing due to the

`Does C:\USERS\ALLID\DESKTOP\batchtesting2\testing.txt specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?`

here is my command line:

```
XCOPY "c:\USERS\me\DESKTOP\batchtesting\testing.txt" "c:\USERS\me\DESKTOP\batchtesting2\testing.txt" /i /e
```

However, the `/i` isn't working to avoid the prompt.

Comment: You don't need to specify the file name in the target. `XCOPY "c:\USERS\me\DESKTOP\batchtesting\testing.txt" "c:\USERS\me\DESKTOP\batchtesting2\" /i /e`

Comment: As @Squashman says, leaving off the filename in the destination solves the issue, but usually requires you to include a final backslash, as the sample provided shows.